# Fixed footer in sidenav

Tags: html, angularjs, css, flexbox

I am trying to add a fixed textarea(sidebar-dir-2) in a sidenav. This textarea must be always at the bottom of the browser window. I can't seem to achieve this. Every time I use fixed positioning the sidebar-dir-2 is set to the bottom of the browser screen but as I scroll it stays in the middle of the screen. Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap">
     <md-toolbar class="md-blue-grey" >
          <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">
               <span>Sidebar</span>
          </h1>
     </md-toolbar>

     <sidebar-dir-1></sidebar-dir-1>


</div>
<sidebar-dir-2 style="position: fixed; bottom: 0"></sidebar-dir-2>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i gathered from want you wanted is it similar to this?

```
   <style>
        textarea{
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 50%;
        }
        </style>
```

---

```
<textarea>Something</textarea>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to achieve. The problem is that the sidebar is scrollable. But when I scroll sidebar-dir-2 stays in a the middle of the page. I expected it to stick to the bottom as I scrolled.

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident  well i am runing this and it's working fine there is no issue with the code you are giving